# Which Sci-Fi work introduced the idea of "Energy Swords"?

Tags: history-of

There are [countless Sci-Fi works featuring Energy Swords](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/54318/931). But, which one was the first? Which one bring this idea in the world?

Strict definition of an *Energy Sword* can be complex because of variations of swords (Plasma blade, Concentrated Photon blade, Low heat blade etc). Just take reference of Lightsabers (Star Wars). Some features I am highlighting however:

- The blade isn't made of any kind of solid matter (fictional or real).
- The blade is projected as light beam which can be turned off.

Comment: How about the [Kzinti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kzin) swords from Larry Niven's [Known Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known_Space) books? IIRC they were a single strand of monomolecular filament held straight by a force-field. The "blade" could be effectively turned off - reeled back into the pommel.

Comment: @JoeL Reeling back doesn’t look like *lights out* thing, so it may not qualify.

Answer (score 6):

According to TV Tropes under [Laser Blade](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LaserBlade): "the Trope Maker is the "force knife" from the *[Lucky Starr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_Starr_series)* novels written by Isaac Asimov under the pen-name Paul French in the 1950s." Lucky had a blade made out of a forcefield which was preternaturally sharp, particularly when manifested in something.

Comment: The link in my question shows earlier works.

Comment: {nods} But the Kaldar ones are a metal blade encircled by energy and the "rods of wrath" by Leiber don't stop.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 Are you looking for anything additional in an answer?

Comment: @BabyYoda: Re-iterating, can I add anything to this for you?